# How to implement lazy loading using Ghost object in java?

Tags: java, architecture, lazy-loading

I've reading Martin Fowler's book chapter about lazy loading.

Author provides example of Lazy loading via Ghost object on C# which I don't know. I tried to understand overall meaning but I was not successful because there are a lot of classes involved and book doesn't contain enough explanation to undertstand. Also I tried to search example using Google but all places I found linked me to the PHP example which I don't know either.

Could you provide example on Java ?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Unfortunately not

Comment: Is there a language translation involved here? I've never heard the term "ghost object", and Google doesn't seem to bring up anything relevant.

Comment: @chrylis please find ghost word here: https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html maybe it is Fowler's invention

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly (I'm looking at https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html), then I don't know of a way to get this functionality directly in Java; you'll have to use one of the other principles and wrap it in a ghost object wrapper.

Basically, you initialize your object with the minimal set of values, then compute the other field values only when necessary. Something like the code below would give you a lazy way to get a `Complicated` object off a `Ghost`. I've seen objects like this used when loading information from a database but don't know when you'll need it, or when computing a particularly complicated or heavyweight hashcode.

```
public class Ghost {

    private final int count;
    private boolean initialized = false;
    private Complicated complicated = null;

    public Ghost(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Complicated getComplicated(String extraValue) {
        // could also check (here and below) this.complicated == null
        // in that case doExpensiveOperation should not return null, and there shouldn't be other fields to initialize
        if (!initialized) {
            synchronized(this) { // if you want concurrent access
                if (!initialized) {
                    complicated = doExpensiveOperation(extraValue);
                    initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return complicated;
    }

    private Complicated doExpensiveLoad(String extraValue) {
        // do expensive things with this.count and extraValue
        // think database/network calls, or even hashcode calculations for big objects
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between ValueHolder and Ghost?

Comment: (If I understand this correctly) In my example, the outer class is a Ghost because as far as a consumer is aware, this object was fully loaded already, but inside the class we use Lazy Initialization to actually load values. A ValueHolder puts the onus on the consumer to initialize the object with a call to a `getValue` method. In Java, something like `Suppliers#memoize` from Guava is an example of a ValueHolder (If I'm understanding this right).